# docker export import and USER

Tags: docker

I have a docker image with `USER bigtop` in the Dockerfile. I do:

```
docker run myimage SOMETHING
docker export > GIANTTARBALL
docker import GIANTTARBALL imported
docker run -it imported bash
```

I am sitting in /root running as the root. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker export` command will export the container filesystem (no Docker image or runtime metadata). See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/.

Essentially, when you export the filesystem this way, you lose any of the Docker specific instructions including `USER`.

It is worth noting that you *can* export from images (not containers) and save the image and metadata in a tarball using `docker save`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#usage.

Comment: So, either way I lose something? save does not capture the state as of when the container shut down, and export does not capture USER and such.

Comment: Correct. `save` is for an image, not a container. But you can mimic this by doing a `docker commit` on the container and commit the image to a tag and then `save` that image.